# Python add input to a command's prompt

Tags: python, macros, scripting, automation

I'm trying to write a quick python script to automate the process of building OpenVPN certificates/keys.

Currently we use the "build-key" script from EasyRSA, and I'd like to continue using this script. Build key starts generating a key, and then prompts you for information like "name" or "email address". Essentially I'd like my Python script to input this all for me and hit yes to all the prompts so that I can "batch create" keys.

My problem is a quick search hasn't suggested a way to let python add input to these prompts. I know I can run a command in python, but I need to interact with it during its runtime to enter input and accept prompts. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/172509/openvpn-easy-rsa-build-key-automation)

Comment: Is this windows or linux? On linux you can interact using the pexpect module. There isn't anything nice on windows. Sometimes you can get away with just sending the answers to the prompts on the subprocess stdin (with Popen.communicate for instance). But really, you want to see if the script can be run entirely from command line arguments.

Comment: @tdelaney Thankfully this is linux! I'll have a look into seeing if the script can be run with arguments.